# Using a patched Scala 2.9.0-1 (patched REPL) in sbt 0.10?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a Scala project that depends on a number of libraries built
against 2.9.0-1. I'm interested in applying a new small patch from
upstream that fixes the Scala REPL to no longer execute each line in a
new thread. I should be able to download the Scala sources, apply the
patch, and ant-build everything myself, but is there any way to make
sbt (or at least the `console` command) use this build?

It's also important to be able to reproduce this environment on all
our dev boxes, so we're interested in minimizing out-of-band hacks. We
have a corp maven repository, but not sure how to "override" things
such that Scala 2.9.0-1 is fetched from here (if that's even the best
approach for this problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish the custom Scala jars to the corporate repository with a unique version and use that unique version as the value for your `scalaVersion` setting.  Reusing the same version for different artifacts is problematic for caches as well as keeping track of exactly which jar is being used.

To set the Scala version used to locate [cross-built](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build) managed dependencies, such as

```
"net.databinder" %% "dispatch-http" % "0.8.5"
```

use the following setting:

```
scalaVersion in update := "2.9.0-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is to ask Paul if that feature could be included in the 2.9.1.

Next try would be just using a working nightly.

Last chance will be applying patches.

Comment: Paul suggested that I apply the patch to 2.9.0.1. In any case I'm avoiding using a nightly because I don't want to break compatibility with all my 2.9.0 library dependencies.